# Camel REST Bean Chaining

Tags: java, apache-camel

I currently have a REST route builder that looks as follows:

```
rest("/v1")
  .post("/create")
    .to("bean:myAssembler?method=assemble(${in.header.content})")
    .to("bean:myService?method=create(?)");
```

The bean myAssembler takes raw JSON and transforms this into MyObject. This object is then returned and I want it forwarded onto myService as a parameter for its create method.

How can I do this using Camel?

Comment: PLease share the code you have written so far in `Camel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your beans will bind automatically to specific parameters like Exchange if you put it as a parameter to a method (see complete list [Parameter binding](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html)).

One solution would be to define your route and beans like this:

```
restConfiguration()
.component("restlet")
.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
.skipBindingOnErrorCode(false)
.port(port);    

rest("/v1")
    .post("/create")
        .route()
            .to("bean:myAssembler?method=assemble")
            .to("bean:myService?method=create");
```

with beans like this

```
public class MyAssembler {
    public void assemble(Exchange exchange) {
      String content = exchange.getIn().getHeader("content", String.class);
      // Create MyObject here.
      MyObject object; // ...transformation here.
      exchange.getOut().setBody(object);
   }
}
```

and this

```
public class MyService {
    public void create(MyObject body) {
        // Do what ever you want with the content.
        // Here it's just log.
        LOG.info("MyObject is: " + body.toString());
     }
}
```

The dependencies for shown configuration are

```
org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.15.3
org.apache.camel/camel-spring/2.15.3
org.apache.camel/camel-restlet/2.15.3
javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0
org.apache.camel/camel-jackson/2.15.3
org.apache.camel/camel-xmljson/2.15.3
xom/xom/1.2.5
```

Comment: Nice, would it be possible to pass the actual object instead of the Exchange to MyService?

Comment: Yes it would. I've updated the answer so that MyService will now get "MyObject body" as a parameter.

Comment: Just gave the solution a try and I'm getting InvalidPayloadException no body available of type MyObject

Comment: Can you add the rest of the exception? What is the location where you get this exception? The code above is working for me but MyObject is obviously different than yours.

Comment: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: com.myapp.application.dto.MyObject but has value:  of type: java.lang.String on: HttpMessage@0x4dbdd4d5. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: com.myapp.application.dto.MyObject with value . Exchange[HttpMessage@0x4dbdd4d5]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: com.myapp.application.dto.MyObject with value

Comment: Your problem is that you are setting somewhere message body to a String when MyService expects MyObject class. Hard to say exactly what to fix without seeing more of your actual code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89597/discussion-between-jnupponen-and-infinite217).

Comment: As discussed, it looks like I had servlet defined in my rest configuration as opposed to restlet. Changing this I was able to pass the objects between my beans.

Comment: Here is the Rest configuration -

        restConfiguration()
                .component("restlet")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
                .skipBindingOnErrorCode(false)
                .port(port);

Comment: I've updated the solution with your restConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if last bean returns `MyObject`, next bean can accept and bind `MyObject` as first arg. You don't need to put it into Exchange body or anything.